# How to use conditional statement to check whether array equal to a row of matrix?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have an array of int type, I want check that if all elements of this array are equal to the elements of i-th row of m×n matrix. For example:

```
array={5,0,2,3};
```

and

```
matrix={{1,3,2,2}{5,0,2,3}{2,1,2,9}};
```

so if

```
array[j] = matrix[i][j];
```

for all `j=0,1,2` then

```
print("the wanted i is: "+i);
```

I have written this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int i, j, m=3, n=4;
    int[][] A0 = {{0,2,2,5},{2,0,3,1},{0,2,0,5}}; 
    int[] A={0,2,0,5};
    int seq = 0;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
       for(j=0;j<n;j++){
          if(A[j] != A0[i][j]){
             break;
          }
          seq= i;
       }
    }
    System.out.print(seq);
}
```

But its not work well because it always continue checking until final row.
Is there is any other better idea? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all,
if any value is different in a row,
then you want to skip to the next iteration of the outer loop.
You can do that by giving the outer loop a label,
and the `continue` statement.

Secondly,
as soon as you found a row where all values match,
you can break out of the outer loop.

```
    OUT: for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (A[j] != A0[i][j]) {
                continue OUT;
            }
        }
        seq = i;
        break;
    }
```

By using `Arrays.equals` you can simplify by quite a lot,
by eliminating the inner loop,
and with it all the label + continue black magic:

```
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        if (Arrays.equals(A, A0[i])) {
            seq = i;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two `for`conditions. So when you reach

```
if(A[j] != A0[i][j]) {
   break;
}
```

You will break the  only this for loop, so you will continue the other loop:

```
 for(i=0;i<m;i++) {
```

So you have to break this one too, here is a solution

```
boolean canBreak = false;
for(i=0;i<m;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
        if(A[j] != A0[i][j]) {
            canBreak = true;
            break;
        }
        if (canBreak) break;
        seq= i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`Arrays.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(int[],%20int[]))

```
private int[][] matrix;

public boolean equalsRow(int[] row, int index) {
  return Arrays.equals(row, matrix[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    private int[][] myArray;

    public boolean equalsRow(int[] row, int x) 
    {
       return Arrays.equals(row, myArray[x]);
    }
```

simpler

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int i, j, m=3, n=4;int ct=0;
    int[][] A0 = {{0,2,2,5},{2,0,3,1},{0,2,0,5}}; 
    int[] A={0,2,0,5};
    int seq = 0;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
       for(j=0;j<n;j++){
          if(A[j] == A0[i][j]){
           ct++;
          } 
          else
          {
              break;
              }

           }
       if(ct==4)
       { 
           seq=i;
           break;
       }

       ct=0;
    }
    System.out.print(seq);
}
```